# How to focus a field that was updated using p:ajax?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've got a problem with my PrimeFaces application.

Imagine a dropdown (`p:selectOneMenu`) and a keyboard field (`p:keyboard`).
The dropdown is like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu
    id="artikelUserAuswahl"
    style="width: 80%;"
    filter="true"
    filterMatchMode="#{userBean.sucheMethodeArtikelKasse}"
    value="#{kassenController.artikelNummerDropdown}"
    disabled="#kassenController.tooMuch}"
    onchange="$(function(){PrimeFaces.focus('formKasse:anzahl');});">
        <f:selectItem
            itemLabel="#{resourceUtils.getI18N('label.artikel.waehlen')}"
            itemValue=""
            itemDisabled="true"
            noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems
            value="#{kioskArtikelController.recordListIncludeSelected}"
            var="ki"
            itemLabel="#{ki.text}"
            itemValue="#{ki.artikelNummer}"/>
        <p:ajax
            update=":formKasse :formKasse:artikelNummer :formKasse:anzahl :formKasse:preis
                    formKasse:artikelBeschreibung :formKasse:bestandVorhanden :formKasse:buttonAbschluss"   
            listener="#{kassenController.addArtikelDropdown}" />
        <p:focus for="preis" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And I have the `p:keyboard` field:

```
<p:keyboard
    id="#{userBean.kioskKasseUseNumpadPreis ? 'anzahl' :'anzahlNotRendered'}"
    value="#{kassenController.anzahlAsString}"
    layout="custom"
    layoutTemplate="123,456,789,0.,back-close"
    backspaceLabel="#{resourceUtils.getI18N('label.keyboard.backspace')}"
    styleClass="kioskNumpadRabatt"
    rendered="#{userBean.kioskKasseUseNumpadMenge}"
    style="width: 80%; border: 2px solid #eeeeee !important;"
    autocomplete="off"
    disabled="#{kassenController.tooMuch}"
    tabindex="2" />
```

Now don't get me wrong, everything is working in terms of values, beans and also the form (everything is displayed correctly), but I get this weird behavior, that if I select a value from the dropdown, the keyboard shows, but if I click on a number (for example "1" on the PrimeFaces keyboard), then it wont add it to the input field, because the focus is not really there.

[image]

But as soon as I manually click in the `p:keyboard` field, it works properly (Problem: the final product will run on touch-screen monitor).

PrimeFaces version: 6.0.

Comment: 1: Always post PF version info. 2: What if you run ` PrimeFaces.focus('formKasse:anzahl');}`  from the browser developer console? 3: What if you remove the ajax update? What if you do the focus AFTER the ajax update (in its oncomplete) or...

Comment: No, please let me create an answer. And your edits would better have been posted as comments

Comment: Normally it is not wrong if you answer your own questions. But in cases where others really help you, it is good practice to ask if they want to write an answer or not. In this case I'd like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the focus is done before the ajax update. So the ajax update will fire after you set the focus. Since in this ajax call you also update the field you just set the focus to, it will undo setting this focus.

Solution is to set the focus in the oncomplete of the ajax call of the `p:selectOneMenu` :

```
<p:ajax
    update=":formKasse :formKasse:artikelNummer :formKasse:anzahl :formKasse:preis
                formKasse:artikelBeschreibung :formKasse:bestandVorhanden :formKasse:buttonAbschluss"   
    listener="#{kassenController.addArtikelDropdown}" 
    oncomplete="$(function(){PrimeFaces.focus('formKasse:anzahl');});" 
 />
```